# How to reconnect to MySQL if server has gone away

Tags: yii2

Is there any Yii2 native option to reconnect to MySQL in case of the lost connection? I mean at yii\db components level. Looked though these components, but found only $this->db->close() and $this->db->open(); but they do not work as expected. Tried to use pool of masters in config, again not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autoReconnect=true` in your database connection string:

```
mysql://db_user:db_user@localhost/mydb?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such attribute at Yii2 database component. Possibly you are using some custom package.

Comment: Yeah no... Basically what it says in the Yii docs is that dsn can be a connection string as specified by the PHP docs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#$dsn-detail and here https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php I am using the `URI` format in my answer.

Comment: If that does not work, you can just try to add it as an option to the options array in the `Connection`.

Comment: Tried, just in case, but still the same. Checked Mysql docs, such option was not mentioned there: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/apis-php-pdo-mysql.html and here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-ref.pdo-mysql.connection.html

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you can try doing this.

```
// check if Database component is initialised
if (property_exists(Yii::$app, 'db')) {
    // get component object
    $oDb = Yii::$app->db;
    assert($oDb instanceof \yii\db\Connection);

    // open a new connection if the old one is not active
    if (!$oDb->isActive) {
        $oDb->open();
    }
}
```

You should paste this code before querying a database.

Answer (score -1):

2 solutions by сaptain Obvious:

- [define by INI configuration file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.reconnect)
- add event handler calling before query